# How can we skip records in mongodb stitch?

Tags: mongodb-stitch

I can see the limit option in mongoDB Stitch [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/actions/collection.find/) but unable to find how can we skip records for pagination.

[image]

Comment: Hi~ i have same issues while using mongodb Stitch... Did you find any good solution to fix this issue?? I saw Stitch doesn't support Skip() function.

Answer (score 8):

You can use aggregate with pipeline. Something like that:

```
exports = function(arg){
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const coll = mongodb.db(<dbname>).collection(<collectionname>);

  const pipeline = [
    { "$skip" : 1 },
    { "$limit": 20 }
  ];

return coll
    .aggregate(pipeline)
    .toArray();

};
```

Comment: unfortunately, this IS the only way at the moment. (Still)

Answer (score -2):

this will skip 1st 100 doc from the result

```
db.collection.find({query}).skip(100)
```

here query is what you queried for.

Comment: i am talking about stitch not core mongodb. when i try this it gives me error "TypeError: 'skip' is not a function".